# How do I make sure my NGINX server is using TLS instead of SSL for authentification?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I've added:
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

to the top of my nginx.conf and restarted using:
sudo service nginx restart

How can I be sure that my nginx server is now using TLS exclusively?

Thanks from a sysadmin nub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox or Chrome, visit your site and click on the lock in the address bar. Then click on "Connection" (in Chrome) or "More Information" (in Firefox). See if it says, "The connections uses TLS 1.x". That's the easiest way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Set `ssl_protocols`, `ssl_ciphers` & `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`

```
## Use the following SSL defaults
ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers                 ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

## other SSL configs...
```

Run a SSL server test - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

If the server doesn't get at least an "A" grade, then you may want to fix issues that downgrade your grading.